# Why crystal report prompting me for parameter field value while I have written code for it

Tags: crystal-reports

Why crystal report prompting me for parameter field value while I have written code for it.

```java
Private void ReportVeiwer_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ReportDocument reportdoc = new ReportDocument();
    ///string invoice_number = (;
    Invoice invoicerpt = new Invoice();

    ParameterField paramfield = new ParameterField();
    ParameterFields paramfields = new ParameterFields();
    paramfield.Name = "Invoice_Number";
    ParameterDiscreteValue dicval = new ParameterDiscreteValue();
    dicval.Value = User_Info.invoice_number;
    paramfield.CurrentValues.Add(dicval);
    paramfields.Add(paramfield);

    ReportVeiwer rptveiwer = new ReportVeiwer();
    rptveiwer.crystalReportViewer1.ParameterFieldInfo = paramfields;

    reportdoc.Load(@"D:\Furqan\SchoolManagementSystem\SchoolManagementSystem\Invoice.rpt");
    crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = reportdoc;
    reportdoc.SetDatabaseLogon("PC-Name/User", "Password", ".", "Database");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Load the report first. Then, set the parameter value...